# Not able to login in test site while running the test case using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am a newbie to Selenium. Created a login test case for my test suite using Selenium IDE, saved it in HTML format, saved in a Test suite.All the test cases in the test suite passes in IDE.

When I run the test suite using Selenium RC using the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -htmlSuite *firefox https://www.com "/home/../../../Automationtestcases.html" "/tmp/test.html".
```

It enters the username,password,taps on submit but login is not successful.

Am not able to guess the problem? Can someone help?

Example code:

```
@Test public void testSuccessfullogin() throws Exception { 
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setSpeed | 6000 | ]]
    driver.get("hemoclo.com/hemocloapp/index.html"); 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control")).sendKeys("dranjali");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("Dranjali123*‌​");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Submit']")).click(); 
    try { 
        assertEquals("Signed in as Anjali Naregal", 
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Signed in as Anjali Naregal")).getText()); 
    } catch (Error e) { 
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString()); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: By "login is not successful", what do you mean? Is the username and password incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the username and password are correct.After clicking on the login button it stays in the same login page and the test case fails.

Comment: Did you try inserting a small wait period of 1 second before the button click? In my experience Selenium (sometimes) has trouble clicking on buttons.

Comment: Yep tried giving Pause for 9 secs.Its still the same.

Comment: Sanity Check: After you execute the above script, are you able to manually click on that button?

Comment: @Test
  public void testSuccessfullogin() throws Exception {
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setSpeed | 6000 | ]]
    driver.get("https://hemoclo.com/hemocloapp/index.html");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control")).sendKeys("dranjali");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).clear();

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("Dranjali123*");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Submit']")).click();
    try {
      assertEquals("Signed in as Anjali Naregal", driver.findElement(By.linkText("Signed in as Anjali Naregal")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

Comment: I stopped the script and entered the username/password on the browser launched by the Selenium RC server manually.Its the same behaviour nothing happened.Is there a problem with the webpage loading?

Comment: I edited your post to include the code. Also, lets move this discussion over to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a sendKeys(${KEY_ENTER}) to simulate a click

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code here is one suggestion:

- Locate the "id" of your Submit button. Do this by using a tool such as [Xpath Helper plugin for Chrome.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en)
- The ID (of any element) usually has the following form in the Xpath: `@id='button-id'`
- Once you locate the button ID: replace `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Submit']")).click();` by `driver.findElement(By.id("button-id")).click();`

Another suggestion (more like a sanity check):

- Load a **completely new session** of your browser. (Do not use the browser opened by Selenium). Load your page, enter credentials and hit submit. Check that the page goes through.